# Finding determinant of an infinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to find the simplest way to get an expression of the  determinant of the following infinite matrix as m tends to infinity.

$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & a_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\beta_{1} & 1 & a_{2} & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & \beta_{2} & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & a_{m}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \beta_{m} & 1
\end{array} \right]$$

I have considered using both the Leibniz formula or the Laplace formula.
Leibniz formula required considering sums over permutations which I was hoping to avoid and Laplace formula seems somewhat recursive even though I have only 2-3 elements in each row it. Is there a simpler solution to this problem which I am overlooking ?

Edit:
I am just after an algebraic expansion of the determinant into and infinite series of some kind ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The criteria for absolute convergence of this determinant is given by Whittaker & Watson section 2.82 p37 as an example due to von Koch. It is probably a good idea to confirm your case satisfies this necessary and sufficient condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try for $\lambda=-1$

$$ \det(I-\lambda K) = \left[
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-\lambda)^n \operatorname{Tr } \Lambda^n(K) \right]=
 \exp{ \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\operatorname{Tr} K^n}{n} (-\lambda)^n \right)}$$

where $\Lambda^n (K)$ is the $n$th exterior power of $K$.

copied from

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_determinant

Note that $I-K$ can be put as $D^+ + D^-$, where $D^+$ are strict upper triangular and $D^-$ are strict lower diagonal. Then use the binomial theorem for $(D^+ + D^-)^n$.

Note that $(D^-)^k$ and $(D^+)^k$ are fairly simple to compute;)

Comment: I am not sure the method you are suggesting is much simpler, if anything it seems quite the opposite.

Comment: I provided you with a further hint;) The binomial theorem is now doing the combinatorics for you;)

Comment: thanks i 'll try it out and would post back if i run into trouble.